# How can I see files that are loaded locally in the Firefox dev tools?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I need to use Firefox for a specific project that I am debugging. The project is running locally. When opening the Firefox developer tools and go to the Network tab, it's not showing any of the files being imported. I do see them being loaded in Chrome and IE but I specifically need to use FF for this.

Obviously, I have refreshed the page but no luck. Is there a setting I am missing to activate the network tracking of locally loaded files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option/setting for that, because that's a missing feature & already reported as [bug 1000540](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1000540)

Comment: Thank you. Wow. That's a big oversight. It says it was reported 3 years ago.  Surprising that they haven't fixed that yet. You'd think it'd be an important feature.

Comment: One workaround I've used is to run a simple local web server.  Python ships with one, for example.

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood Sadly you right, there is some huge bugs/missed feature still exists in FFDT (_also Firefox itself_), let's pray to see all of them fixed in 2017.

Comment: I've followed @TomTromey's advice and am now using a local server. It's a step I would have liked to avoid because there's nothing in the site that actually requires a server but it solves the problem for now.

Comment: jesus... 2022 and this still doesn't work... ‍♂️

Comment: There's some progress: In version 124 beta / 125 nightly you see the html document loaded, with status 200 OK, but without document content. Resources (<img src="image.png">) seem not to be implemented or not complete.